# Image or view on the left side of a static table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I created a table with 2 static cells. I managed to add a label or image on the left side of a cell. However how can I change the middle grey line to have more padding to the left?

[image]

so that it looks like in the iOS settings. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: have you tried the `–setSeparatorInset:` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

From the above screen shot change the value which is highlighted in red color

Answer (score 1):

Right here playboy

Just click the table cell in `Storyboard` and change this value

[image]